# Farming problem - seed planted but no plants appearing

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I created two farm plots, all of them with plump helmets seeds. The seeds are planted and everything seems okay, but two seasons have passed and nothing has grown. My dwarves are starving right now and I don't know why this is happening.  I destroyed the farm plots and created new ones only to get the same problem.

I am using the Masterwork mod.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look in the Masterwork Settings and see if Harder Farming is checked on the Misc. Features tab. This setting causes plants to take much longer to grow, and is almost certainly the cause of your problem.

You will need to close Dwarf Fortress, uncheck that setting, launch Dwarf Fortress again and **generate a new world**. If you try to play in any currently created worlds, the crops will still be slow.

Comment: tnx, i ll try to survive 2 seasons ...

Comment: It mostly just means that you need to have much bigger farms than usual.

Comment: Above ground plants only need 2 seasons to grow. Planted in spring/ summer they can help you survive the first year.

Comment: @BackStaB Ah, that's good to know. I'm usually desperately fishing and buying food from caravans until I get a big farm going.